# Install emacs by homeberry in macOS 13.1 M1 Pro

Tags: macos, emacs, homebrew

It give me error like this,

Error: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: 6228b41938ad3ef76450c843a510615b07f8058bc9a256d1ff3fbf928a384235
Actual: b2bd1f0dcdc8e5be37f613310572b23e022cc42b950cb3860a9f4aaad1fd426a
File: /Users/zhengbowen/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/30054abe2047cb9d07b740dee1c1668109f922f3ed1815f2d9c02eccd95ef883--Emacs-28.2-universal.dmg
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.

Even though I removw the file it metioned above and retry, it still gives me the same error, what should I do?

Comment: do what the error message suggests, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just have some cache problem. It might be good to run `brew cleanup --prune=all` to clear all the cache and try again